# Typical file structure in Reactjs application: grouping API calls in api.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Just wanted to know how to group all of my API calls altogether in an **api.js** file, in my React App (just some pseudocode would work). I have read an [interesting article](https://daveceddia.com/react-project-structure/) that introduces that idea, and I feel curious because that file structure really fits my needs. How would it be?
Moreover, the author states in a comment:

> *I usually just put all of my API calls into that file - they're
>   usually small one-or-two-line functions that call out to axios, and I
>   just export them.*
>
> *export function login(username, password) { ... } export function
>   getFolders() { ... } etc.*

But I feel it lacks some details to reproduce it. I am new to Javascript and React. Thanks.

Comment: Just start writing code. Then you will understand what he means :)

Comment: If you think your app will grow and will have many asynchronous ajax calls and state management scenarios, I would suggest looking at (redux + redux observable) or (redux + redux-saga). This would make app simpler and manageable. https://redux.js.org/ https://redux-observable.js.org/ https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Say you are using axios for http calls, I guess it would be smth like this:

api.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { resolve } from './resolve.js';

export async function login(user, pass) {
  return await resolve(axios.post('http://some-api.com/auth', { user, pass }).then(res => res.data));
}

export async function getUser(id) {
  return await resolve(axios.get(`http://some-api.com/users/${id}`).then(res => res.data));
}

// and so on....
```

And as he said on the post, If your files starts to get too big, you can create a `src/api/` and create separate files like `src/api/auth.js`, `src/api/users.js`, etc..

To resolve the promises I like to use the new `async/await` syntax and wrap it in a little module resolver.js:

```
export function async resolve(promise) {
  const resolved = {
    data: null,
    error: null
  };

  try {
    resolved.data = await promise;
  } catch(e) {
    resolved.error = e;
  }

  return resolved;
}
```

And your component smth like:

```
// ...
componentDidMount() {
  this.getUser();
}

async getUser() {
  const user = await api.getUser(this.props.id);
  if(user.error)
    this.setState({ error: user.error });
  else
    this.setState({ user: user.data });
}
```

Again, this is something I like to do, I think the code looks clearer, keeping a synchronous structure. But I guess it's perfectly fine to resolve your promises with `.then()` and `.catch()` also.

I hope that helped!

Comment: Of course, but I was wondering the "importing" side. I would do it in the componentDidMount lyfecycle method, but... What about the error handling? In api.js or right in the calling component? Is there any convention about it? Thanks

Comment: Idk if there is a convention.. In my projects I like to have a little module to resolve the promises and always return a object with error and result. I will edit the answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how much API functions a project has.
I usually stick with project structure called "grouping by file type" mentioned in [React official website](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html#grouping-by-file-type) and keep API related files in a separate directory where every file has an API functionality dedicated to a specific entity.

However, for small projects, it makes sense to keep all API functionality in one file.

Comment: Thanks for that link. Following the official React guidelines tends to be always a good choice :)